# Prevent component re-render with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I try to figure out why a `styled-component` `button` is re-rendered when I click on it, while there is no re-render when the `button` is not styled.

I have a function component that renders a clickable `button` styled with `styled-components`. When the `button` is clicked, the action is triggered as expected but the styled `button` is re-rendered on each click and I can see from the chrome devtools that a new `class` is generated each time.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = ({ onClickButton }) => {
  const WrappedButton = styled.button`
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
  `;

    return (
      <WrappedButton 
        type="button"
        onClick={onClickButton} 
      />
    )
};

export default Button;
```

When the button is not styled, the action is triggered and the button is not re-rendered, as expected:

```
return (
  <button 
    type="button"
    onClick={onClickButton} 
  />
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What does onClickButton do? You set state in there, at a guess?

Comment: I don't think it's the _cause_ but you should move `WrappedButton` outside of the `Button`. That will be recreated _every time the `Button` renders_

Comment: It's a function connected to a redux store in a parent component.

Comment: Thanks @skovy. I moved the styles outside the function component and it works now ! You should make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should move the `WrappedButton` outside of the `Button`. That will be recreated every time the `Button` renders. This is likely what is accounting for the new class in every re-render.

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled from "styled-components";

const WrappedButton = styled.button`
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
`;

const Button = ({ onClickButton }) => {
  return <WrappedButton type="button" onClick={onClickButton} />;
};

export default Button;
```

Comment: This was super helpful! I had a transition on my `styled-component` that wasn't firing because the styled-component was re-rendering every time. Pulling it out of the component helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try hoisting the WrappedButton component initialisation outside of the render function as follows and use React.memo to memoize/make the component a `PureComponent`

```js
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const WrappedButton = memo(styled.button`
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
  `);

const Button = memo(({ onClickButton }) => {

    return (
      <WrappedButton 
        type="button"
        onClick={onClickButton} 
      />
    )
});

export default Button;
```